# Flutter YouTube iframe fullscreen failed on some devices

Tags: flutter, youtube, youtube-player-flutter

I have an flutter app show some YouTube videos, in some devices...
Specifically Samsung A series & Poco mobiles

The videos are displayed in full screen mode like the image shown below

[image: full screen mode]

**Note that:**
The full screen mode displayed normal on all devices [Android & iOS] and this error happen only on Samsung A series & Poco mobiles

*here my code:*

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Stack(

  children: [

    Container(

      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
      color: Colors.black,
      child: Center(
        child:
        YoutubePlayerBuilder(

          player: YoutubePlayer(
            controller: _controller,

            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,

            showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
            progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            topActions: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(width: 8.0),
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  _controller.metadata.title,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                  ),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 1,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.settings,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 25.0,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  //log('Settings Tapped!');
                },
              ),
            ],
            onReady: () {
              _isPlayerReady = true;
            },
            onEnded: (data) {

            },
          ),

          builder: (context, player) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: kRedColor,
              leading: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 40,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                ),
              ),
              title: const Text(
                'للرجوع للخلف إسحب الشاشة لأسفل',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  player,
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        _space,
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            _text(
                              'Playback Quality',
                              _controller.value.playbackQuality ?? '',
                            ),
                            const Spacer(),
                          ],
                        ),
                        _space,
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              icon: ImageIcon(
                                AssetImage("assets/icons/Back.png"),
                                //color: Color(0xFF3A5A98),
                              ),
                              tooltip: "10 Seconds",
                              onPressed: _isPlayerReady
                                  ? () => rewindTo()
                                  : null,
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                _controller.value.isPlaying
                                    ? Icons.pause
                                    : Icons.play_arrow,
                              ),
                              onPressed: _isPlayerReady
                                  ? () {
                                _controller.value.isPlaying
                                    ? _controller.pause()
                                    : _controller.play();
                                setState(() {});
                              }
                                  : null,
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              icon: ImageIcon(
                                AssetImage("assets/icons/Forward.png"),
                                //color: Color(0xFF3A5A98),
                              ),
                              tooltip: "10 Seconds",
                              onPressed: _isPlayerReady
                                  ? () => seekTo()
                                  : null,
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(_muted ? Icons.volume_off : Icons.volume_up),
                              onPressed: _isPlayerReady
                                  ? () {
                                _muted
                                    ? _controller.unMute()
                                    : _controller.mute();
                                setState(() {
                                  _muted = !_muted;
                                });
                              }
                                  : null,
                            ),
                            FullScreenButton(
                              controller: _controller,
                              color: kRedColor,
                            ),

                          ],
                        ),
                        _space,
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            const Text(
                              "Volume",
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Slider(
                                activeColor: kRedColor,
                                inactiveColor: Colors.transparent,
                                value: _volume,
                                min: 0.0,
                                max: 100.0,
                                divisions: 10,
                                label: '${(_volume).round()}',
                                onChanged: _isPlayerReady
                                    ? (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _volume = value;
                                  });
                                  _controller.setVolume(_volume.round());
                                }
                                    : null,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        _space,
                        AnimatedContainer(
                          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            color: _getStateColor(_playerState),
                          ),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(80,8,80,8),
                          child: Text(
                            _playerState.toString(),
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),

                        _space,
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Flexible(
                              child: new Text("إذا واجهت بطأً في تحميل الفيديو، قم بإغلاق راوتر الإنترنت من ٣ إلى ٥ دقائق ثم أعد تشغيله",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    WaterMarkWidget(

      text: widget.UsrX,
    ),

  ],/////////////
);
  }
```

**Note that:**

- The stack here to show watermark over the videos
- finally I add container to try to make it in screen center, but failed

  ```
    Container(

   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
  ```